# bootstrap 4 .bg-dark .bg-primary etc isnt working beta 3

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I just pick it from bootstrap 4 documentation at the moment yet it won't give me any background color.

```html
<div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-danger text-white">.bg-danger</div>
<div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-warning text-dark">.bg-warning</div>
```

and when I tried it with card class it's turn into the outline that only getting the color from `.bg-{{color}}` from bootstrap not whole body as promised when I replace it from the documentation itself.

Is it because I'm using the latest bootstrap version alpha 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldnt understand what is the actual problem but here is a snippet working

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-danger text-white">.bg-danger</div>
<div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-warning text-dark">.bg-warning</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the bootstrap stylesheet at the top of your HTML document, and you need to add the `bootstrap scripts` at the bottom of the `body` near the `</body>` tag for `bootstrap` to function correctly.

reference: [https://getbootstrap.com/4.0/getting-started](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/).

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-danger text-white">.bg-danger</div>
<div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-warning text-dark">.bg-warning</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a reference to the boostrap css file inside your `head` tag.

**Bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.6**

```
<head>
....
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">    
</head>
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-danger text-white">.bg-danger</div>
<div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-warning text-dark">.bg-warning</div>
```

**Bootstrap 4.0.0-beta.3**

```
<head>
....
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">    
</head>
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-danger text-white">.bg-danger</div>
<div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-warning text-dark">.bg-warning</div>
```

So your typical page could be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-danger text-white">.bg-danger</div>
    <div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-warning text-dark">.bg-warning</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

mmmm its my fault, i forgot to update my bootstrap file on node_modules within laravel framework... just solved it.. thanks for helping me out anyway guys